# How to populate UITableView with 3 different types of NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

How do I populate a UITableView with multiple different types of NSManagedObjects?
I'm building a digital training journal so at present my three types are "Sleep", "Food" & "Water".
I've been successful in using NSFetchedResultsController for 1 object type but generalizing to three not yet.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will use your `NSFetchedResultsController`, and extract each of the managed objects with need, with potentially up to 3 queries (depends on how your database is designed if there are relationships it could just be one).

Once you have this the other part is pretty much the same as you would populate a table with 3 sections. You can do something like this:

```
typedef enum
{
   kMyTableSection1,
   kMyTableSection2,
   kMyTableSection3
}kMyTableSectoinTypes

then in your cellForRowAtIndexpath...

switch (indexpath.section)

case : kMyTableSection1
//Object at index from the correct array which you got from your previous query using the fetched results controller.
```

and so on

Hope that helps.

Comment: What if I made the different managed objects subclasses of a managed object called "Event" and then just fetch all events.

Comment: The fact that they are subclasses or not does not change the fetch, what you can do to fetch everything at once, is if they are related you can set up relationships in your database, that way one fetch can bring all the objects you need.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit challenging to do with an NSFetchedResultsController, since it's typically initialized with with an NSFetchRequest, which in turn takes only one entity. I believe you should either:

a. Fetch all the data yourself from Core Data regularly, then feed them into the table view as you would normally feed arrays:

```
NSMutableArray *objectsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:sleepEntity];
[objectsArray addObjectsFromArray:[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:waterEntity];
[objectsArray addObjectsFromArray:[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:foodEntity];
[objectsArray addObjectsFromArray:[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL]];

// now display objectsArray in a table view as you normally would.
```

b. Alternatively, you should consider using a framework such as Sensible TableView. With Sensible, you have the advantage of everything being done automatically, including the detail views for objects. I've been using Sensible for some time and I almost don't touch any of the above code.

Comment: Wow. Sensible TableView looks really great.